# How to attach a Thumb to a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, textblock

I have the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="thumb_test.MainWindow" Title="MainWindow" ... >
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Thumb Canvas.Top="25" Canvas.Left="25" Width="50" Height="50"
                Name="_thumb1" DragStarted="ThumbStart" DragDelta="ThumbMoved" >
            </Thumb>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the following is the corresponding code-behind:

```
void ThumbStart(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
{
    _originalLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(_thumb1);
    _originalTop = Canvas.GetTop(_thumb1);
}
void ThumbMoved(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    double left = _originalLeft + e.HorizontalChange;
    double top = _originalTop + e.VerticalChange;
    Canvas.SetLeft(_thumb1, left);
    Canvas.SetTop(_thumb1, top);
    _originalLeft = left;
    _originalTop = top;
}
```

The above displays a rectangle, which can be dragged around on the canvas.

My question: How can I associate this `Thumb` with a `TextBlock`, such that the `Thumb` overlays the `TextBlock` (with the `Thumb` being transparent) and I can drag the `TextBlock` around?  (PS: Believe me, what I have tried so far is not worth showing here.)

My ultimate goal is to be able to drag `TextBlocks` around, so I am open to other approaches.  I would like to operate on a `Canvas`, though.

I am using VS2010 on Win 7, with .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

have you read [Dragging Elements in a Canvas](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas) ?
or this easy way(that i never saw until now -google) [How to make any UI element drag-able using Behaviors in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105637/How-to-make-any-UI-element-drag-able-using-Behavio)